# how can I disable manual inputs in the text input field- JQuery Datepicker

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I  have a text box and I can able to find the ID of that textbox. Binded a JQuery date picker to that text box. My requirement is the user can select the values only through Datepicker. User can't enter value manually.  Is it possible?

Any help is very ppreciated!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

make the textbox readonly

```
<input type="text" size="23" id="dateMonthly" readonly="readonly" style="background:white;" />
```

or via jquery

```
$('#dateMonthly').attr('readonly', true);
```

Comment: Hi Nikola, Thanks for the help. Worked!

Comment: Thanks Nikola it's a very good option if you have minimum date fields but what if their are too many date fields

Comment: @Ravindra First option is to replace id="dateMonthly" with class so you will be able to use that class selector in jquery and you can match many datefields, and the second option is to use Find/Replace feature of your IDE in order to add readonly="readonly".

Comment: @Nikola Yes you are right but i am running out of time and unable to go and add class on each and every fields. I have hundreds of date fields in my application.

Comment: @Ravindra you should find some common selector/selectors than apply the jQuery code

Comment: @Nikola That's a good idea and easy to implement thanks for your comment

Answer (score 2):

Readonly or disabled does not work for me atleast.

> We can override the key events on the input control

```
<input onkeydown="return false" ... />
```

Answer (score 1):

Add "readonly" to the tag.

```
  <input type="text" name="date"  readonly>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

HTML

```
<input class="date-input" type="text" readonly="readonly" />
```

CSS

```
.date-input {
      background-color: white;
      cursor: pointer;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input class="form-control datepicker" id="datepicker" name="sn_rg" placeholder="Fecha de salida y regreso" type="text" required="" >

var dateToday = new Date()
  if (document.querySelector('#datepicker')) {
    flatpickr('#datepicker', {
      mode: "range",
      numberOfMonths: 3,
      showButtonPanel: true,
      minDate: dateToday
    }); // flatpickr 
  }
```

Comment: (This might be the first answer to take the question literally.)

Comment: (You posted to the English SO using a different language. And "hope this helps" is implied in answering, and net really welcome as text: "noise".)